# redirecting stderr influences output of "open FH, '-|', $command". Why and how to prevent?

Tags: perl, file-io, pipe, io-redirection

I want to get the size of the current terminal, i.e. the terminal my perl script is running in. The following should do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub getTerminalSize {
    my @dimensions = (24,80);
    open( my $OH, '-|', "/usr/bin/tput lines ; /usr/bin/tput cols" )
        || return @dimensions;
    chomp(@dimensions = <$OH>);
    close($OH);
    return @dimensions;
}

open (STDERR, ">>bla.log") or die "can not create logfile";
print "Dimensions of your terminal: ". (join " x " , getTerminalSize()) ."\n";
```

Without the last but one line of code it works as it should.
But with this line, I always get 24 x 80 so it seems a new shell is internally created and the size of that shell is returned. Is just my guess.
So what is really happening and how do I get both - redirecting STDERR and the correct size?

Comment: it's a Perl FAQ: [How do I get the screen size?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-get-the-screen-size-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `tput` to identify the terminal size, one of the file descriptors for (<s>stdin</s>,) stdout or stderr must be open and connected to the terminal.

In the pipe construct, `stdout` is connect to the pipe; if you redirect `stderr` to a file then `tput` returns the default size because it does not analyze `stdin`.

So, `tput` has no terminal to work with; it returns the default size of 24x80.

---

You can work around the problem by adding `2>/dev/tty` to the `tput` commands:

```
open my $OH, '-|', "/usr/bin/tput lines 2>/dev/tty; /usr/bin/tput cols 2>/dev/tty"
    or return @dimensions;
```

It appears that `tput` does not look at `stdin` at all.  (Redirecting `stdout` to the terminal would defeat the pipe mechanism Perl is using to read the information, of course.)

---

```
$ tput lines </dev/null
65
$ tput lines </dev/null 2>/dev/null
65
$ x=$(tput lines </dev/null 2>/dev/null)
$ echo $x
24
$
```

I added a diagnostic print in the function to ensure that it was reading the output from `tput`, and it was.  I added these lines to the function:

```
open( my $OH, '-|', "fstat /dev/fd/0 /dev/fd/1 /dev/fd/2 /dev/null")
    or die "horribly";
my(@data) = <$OH>;
close($OH);
print @data;
```

and the output was:

```
   Mode  Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime       Dev      RDev File
0020620    623     1   503     4        0 1333369875 334992488 268435457 /dev/fd/0
0010660 590945904     0   503    20        0 1333369875 334992488         0 /dev/fd/1
0100644 111429666     1   503    20        0 1333369875 334992488         0 /dev/fd/2
0020666    304     1     0     0        0 1333359963 334992488  50331650 /dev/null
```

When run at the command line, the output was:

```
$ fstat /dev/fd/[012] /dev/null
   Mode  Inode Links   UID   GID     Size    Modtime       Dev      RDev File
0020620    623     1   503     4        0 1333370018 334992488 268435457 /dev/fd/0
0020620    623     1   503     4        0 1333370018 334992488 268435457 /dev/fd/1
0020620    623     1   503     4        0 1333370018 334992488 268435457 /dev/fd/2
0020666    304     1     0     0        0 1333359963 334992488  50331650 /dev/null
$
```

So, the standard input of `tput` was still the terminal, but `tput` did not look at that. Therefore, `tput` must have looked at `stderr` (it is not clear whether it tried `stdout`, but that was a pipe) and not at `stdin`.  `fstat` is a home-brew command similar in spirit to `stat`, but it has a different output format.

Comment: well, the script above is complete, i.e. standalone so I do not see where I manipulate stdin?

Comment: thanks a lot so far. But as a quite perl newbie the question: How to "repair" this. How can I make my routine act as it was intended (independent of the "environment")?

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. Incredibly fast, understandable and useful answers!

Comment: This is so right!!! I had the same issue with a shell script (bash) and I relaized only that 24x80 was the default and not the real size... But I didn't know/got/understood how to workaround it. If I could I'd give you 1000k points!!!